# Blurry display with KVM and two PCs

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, resolution, kvm-switch

I have two PCs, both running Windows 7 with integrated Intel graphics chips, both attached to the KVM via VGA and the KVM is VGA to the monitor.

When I switch between displays I notice that one of them is blurry. If I have one PC displayed and run the monitors Auto Adjust feature the blurriness goes away but when I switch to the other PC that one becomes blurry, when I do the Auto Adjust again the same happens when I switch back to the first PC, it's now blurry.

I noticed that the only monitor setting that changes when I do Auto Adjust between the two PCs is the "Phase" value. One PC has a sharp image when phase is at 89 and the other when it's at 29.

Both PCs are running at 1680x1050 at 60Hz so I figured that the issue must be caused by the different advanced display settings such as Front Porch, Pixel Clock, etc.

I wanted to see if I could fix it by creating a custom resolution on both PCs with the same exact advanced settings. The problem is I have no idea what values to set for these advanced settings and I have no idea how to get the default settings of either PC so I could use those.

Can anyone confirm the cause of my issue or have a solution for me?

Answer (score 1):

Hardware KVMs are rarely perfect - software is better.

The free and open-source [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) might solve your 
problem using the local network and without a KVM, so avoiding this hardware headache.

It is basically a network-based software KVM switch
that also does some other goodies such as
sharing your clipboard between the computers.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the two computers are on entirely separate networks so this won't work.

Comment: Entirely separate networks for computers close enough for a KVM??? Note that Synergy only requires a TCP/IP connection between the computers.

Comment: I can't establish any sort of connection between the two computers. One is on a restricted network.

Comment: If both computers have Internet, you can setup a virtual network using [LogMeIn Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/) (free for personal use) or [Comodo Unite](http://www.comodo.com/home/email-security/vpn-access.php). And there are other such free products.

Comment: Both of these would violate security policies on the restricted network.

Comment: With all your restrictions, a hardware KVM might be the only solution, but you might have to try several to find one that works (I had a similar experience). Check well the specs before buying.

Comment: Software is better? I'd like to see a citation for that, otherwise it sounds subjective and I disagree for many situations...

Comment: @AthomSfere: If you find the right hardware the first time, hardware is perfect. But if you don't, then software can be downloaded and tried much easier than running back and forth to the shop, and freeware/shareware doesn't cost a dime to try. Trust me - I once had a really bad experience.

Comment: I trust you, and I trust there are times when software is best (be it Synergy or Mouse Without borders) but it seemed like a bit too much of a blanket statement to me...

Comment: @StickFigs: The virtual lan products I listed are quite secure and really VPNs. My personal experience with LogMeIn Hamachi (before it was LogMeIn), was that it's just perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with the 800 pound gorilla in the room - that old school vga cables can occationally cause blurriness. I'd try switching cables between the two systems to confirm thats not the case. If not, you might be able to export settings from one system to another, assuming they both run windows

I was initially figuring [powerstrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm) from entech would give you the information on what your monitor is - its a tool for monitor and video card tweaking - but I couldn't really find anything relevant there, but if you end up doing some serious experimentation, its the tool for you.

On the other hand, [monitor asset manager](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/moninfo.shtm) should let you dump the data from your monitor to your PC (EDID data) and use the data on the system thats working properly, to set the same settings on the other system, which should, I believe have them working identically. I'd suggest dumping out the initial settings on both (in case) and trying the file from one on the others - if I recall, inf files were simply a plain text file with the necessary information to install a driver, and you could rightclick and install it

Both of these are shareware - powerstrip is for 30 days trial, and monitor asset manager is free for personal use.

Comment: My understanding of the question is there's a single monitor, and I do believe that Monitor Asset Manager can dump edid data as an inf, so you shouldn't need powerstrip at all.

Comment: @harrymc It's a single monitor. Why else would I be using a KVM?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I tried powerstrip and like you said, didn't find any useful information. I then tried what you suggested with monitor asset manager and dumped both PCs .inf files. I compared the two .inf files and they are identical in every way, I don't think installing either on the other will make a difference.

Comment: That would mean that the monitor is reporting the same settings to both systems - so.. there probably isn't a system level software fix, IMO.

Comment: I don't see any of the advanced settings like Front Porch, Pixel Clock, etc. mentioned in these .INF files though, I need a program that can tell me the current settings for those settings on whichever PC.